# Navigation menu not working on google chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, uinavigationbar

I am admin of this page : 
**iuvestudio.com**
My problem occured recently, till september 2017 everything was fine. Now however the navigation menu (top of the site and bottom of the site) is not working on my Google Chrome. If clicked, it just changes color but doesnt move you to right section. It works on Edge however. And maybe it just doesnt work on my Google Chrome but on others it does. I have no idea what should I do to make it work. Any ideas ? I will be very thankful for any suggestions.
Thank you.

Comment: You are required to post a minimal example of your problem markup and code here, not your web site which will change or disappear. [mcve]

Comment: I make sure that I read the sheet later, thank you Sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an event listener added to your `<a>` elements in your plugins.js on line 59. Removing this event listener fixed the issue for me.

You can test it by opening the inspecter (f12) and selecting an `<a>` element in the header. Than open the "Event Listeners" tab and open up the click events. You now find "a plugins:59". Remove this listener and everything works again.

**Edit**:

I added event listeners for the `a` elements to scroll to the id. (I'm only adding these in chrome). The following code was added to your plugins.js file:

```
var is_chrome = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('chrome') > -1;

if (is_chrome) {
    var attributes = ['home', 'whatido', 'myworks', 'about', 'contact'];

    $.each(attributes, function( index, value ) {
        $('a[href="#' + value + '"]').click(function() {
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $('#' + value).offset().top
            }, 1000);
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: The problem after I deleted is that now it just teleport to the right section but before it smoothly moved to right section :(

Comment: If you want us to debug the event handler to see why it's not working in chrome you should provide a unminified snippet of the code.

Comment: Ok, sure here it is : https://send.firefox.com/download/2e9dfb14e9/#m1AfV1rREbJC1GRyO9cbbg

Comment: Ok, this is still minified just like the live example and very difficult to work with. Also when I ask for a snippet I don't mean all the code.. Anyway since I had alot of waiting to do anyway i fixed it for you: You can download the project with fix here: https://send.firefox.com/download/d7a11126f4/#QARvwQYrIgbKooalXiXCwQ

Comment: Thank you very much for your kindness and I am very sorry for my mistakes since I am new here, I didnt really know what you meant by "unminified snippet of the code". Again, Thank you very much

Comment: Please don't answer off topic questions. Answer well-asked questions

Not all questions can or should be answered here. Save yourself some frustration and avoid tryi
ng to answer questions which...
    ...are unclear or lacking specific details that can uniquely identify the problem or supply code here on SO.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer